# AzureML Python SDK v2: How to programmatically stop a compute instance upon creation?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm working on a script that creates compute instances if they don't already exist. Upon creating a compute instance, it is in running state. I'd like to be able to immediately stop that compute instance, as I won't be needing it immediately.

I want to do this using Python with the "new" SDK v2. I am not interested in solutions involving the Idle shutdown time, and scheduled start/stop. I am looking to have direct control on the running state of the instance.

This code works well, but I'd really like to stop the instance as soon as it's created. I haven't found anything relating to this in the documentation.

```py
# This code uses SDK v2    
# MC is MLClient... compute_instance is a ComputeInstance object
mc.compute.begin_create_or_update(compute_instance)
compute_instance.wait()
compute_instance = compute_instance.result()

logger.info(f"Created Compute instance: name={compute_instance.name} size={compute_instance.size}.")

if compute_instance.state == 'Running':
    # I'd like to stop the compute instance HERE!
    logger.warning(f"Compute instance {compute_instance.name} is RUNNING. This costs money.")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up finding my answer on my own, This method uses the SDK 2.0. Note that it is asynchronous, so the function call returns before the stopping is done.

```
# MC is MLClient... compute_instance is a ComputeInstance object    
mc.compute.begin_stop(compute_instance.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the compute instance object of created compute instance as below.

My compute instance name is `jgs-compute`

```
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace
from  azureml.core.compute  import  ComputeInstance

ws  =  Workspace(workspace_name="jgsml",resource_group="your resource group",subscription_id="your subcription id")
compute_instance  =  ComputeInstance(ws,"jgs-compute")
print(f"Compute instance: name={compute_instance.name} size={compute_instance.vm_size}.")
```

[image]

Then execute below to stop.

```
if  compute_instance.status.state  ==  'Running':
    compute_instance.stop(wait_for_completion=True,show_output=True)
```

[image]